# Drag and drop from C# to Windows Explorer with IStorage/IStream

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, windows-explorer, istream, istorage

I've been working on what sounds like simple functionality for way too long now. The idea is that I have an application with a TreeView. This treeview represents contents of a database organized into files and folders, much like Windows Explorer. So it makes sense that the user should be able to drag those files/folders out of my app and into Windows Explorer.

I decided that I should use an `IStream` if they drag a file or an `IStorage` if they drag a folder. After a very long time and learning way more than I ever wanted to know about Win32/COM (and a nudge from a very helpful person here), I finally have that `IStream` or `IStorage` created.

Then I found that to pass this `IStream` or `IStorage` off to Windows Explorer, I had to get it in an `STGMEDIUM`. Of course, the medium.tymed will be either `IStream` or `IStorage`, depending on which I'm using, but as I understand it the `medium.unionmember` must be a pointer to the `IStream/IStorage`.

I've tried using the fixed keyword (but it's not blittable, of course), I've tried just converting the blasted thing to a byte array, but can't come up with a way to make that happen, I've tried using GCHandle to pin it (but it still isn't blittable), and several other things that didn't work.

So my question is this: Given `IStorage s` and `STGMEDIUM m`, how do I populate `m.unionmember` so that Windows Explorer will be happy and accept the drop?

Comment: if anyone knows of a complete implementation of IStream/IStorage for a http URL, please post another answer here, there are few google results for this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168145/download-a-file-using-windows-istream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, C unions are represented using `StructLayout.Explicit` in C#. This probably won't work in your case, however - while you can overlay `IStream` and `IStorage` references like that, the marshaller will try to marshal both. Your best bet is probably to just declare the field as `IntPtr` in your declaration of `STGMEDIUM`, and use `Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject` to initialize it.

Comment: Thanks!  I don't know how I missed GetIUnknownForObject... I think I'm going to have to break down and actually figure out what Marshaling is one day...

Answer (score 0):

I think the topic is outdated by long, however anyone looking for a file drag and drop check out this discussion and especially the post of dbirdz: http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread166429.html

In my eyes this would even apply to this application, I'd try to write my stream into a temporary file which could then be moved to its location.