# download a file using windows IStream

Tags: windows, com, winapi, drag-and-drop, istream

I'm implementing dragging a virtual file out of a website and onto the desktop with an activex control.

How do I create an [IStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380034(v=VS.85).aspx) on my http url, so Windows can execute the drop?

The example I'm looking at uses [SHCreateStreamOnFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759864(VS.85).aspx) to copy a local file; there must be an analogous function for other types of streams like http file download.

Answer (score 4):

How about using the [URL Moniker Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741006%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#URL_Functions). You can use the [URLDownloadToFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (blocking function), or [URLOpenPullStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775128%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (asynchronous).